# NFC tag - data collection using Android Studio

Tags: android, nfc

I've been trying to find an answer for what I had originally thought was a fairly straight-forward question...but for the life of me, I've been unable to do so.

I have an Android app that writes a message (string) to a passive NFC tag. When a user scans the tag, the message I wrote displays, using the native NFC tag reader. (if available).

I'd like to do the following, using Android Studio, if possible:

1. Change the functionality of the "Write To Tag" app...so that it assigns the tag an "ID". I no longer want to have this message display to the user...rather I'd just assign it to a variable that will be used in the next step.
2. Upon scanning, I'd like to create a flat file that is sent to a cloud based database with the following information: 
    -The "ID" of the tag that is scanned. 
    -The date/time of the scan
    -The device type/version that performed the scan, if available
3. For the same scan event, I'd like to direct the user to a web site, unique to each tag. (hard-coded)

Basically, I'm attempting to execute consecutive "send" functions from a single scan. I've never done this before and I'm not even sure if it's possible.

I'm happy to provide any code examples from my "Write To" app if needed...

Comment: can the native NFC tag reader send them to a url?

Comment: Hi Dan, 

Yes, I can send the user to a URL upon scanning. I'm thinking that an alternative method to acheive my goal may be to assign specific URL "links" to specific NFC tags. This way, I'd be able to track which tag was scanned and when...based on website traffic data. If I went that route, though..I'd have to figure out how to code an API that could track that activity...I've never done that either...

Comment: @Leo It's hard to understand what you want. Do you want to ? Use an application A to write unique ID on tag. Use an application B to read this tag, send tag id + info to a web service and application B start browser app with specific url

Comment: Hi @LaurentY, thanks for responding!

I actually just want to write some code that will execute 
when a user "scans" the tag. My solution has changed a little, 
but basically, I'd like to do the following upon scan: 

1. Ask the tag send a flat file to a cloud data storage location with 
the date/time of scan and "ID" of the tag. 


2. Direct the user to requested URL OR send the user a text with link
to URL. 

I'm not sure if a single NFC "scan" can trigger a multi-step code 
instruction?